# Filtering out a foreignkey model out of a foreignkey model

Tags: python, django

Tryna filter all productimg objects of MainProduct but getting `ValueError Cannot use QuerySet for "MainProduct": Use a QuerySet for "Product".` but can't use slug or id to filter it out of Product cuz it's homepage

home:view [doesnt work]

```
#can't use slug here
def home(request):
    mainproduct = MainProduct.objects.all()
    productimg = ProductImage.objects.filter(
        #wanna access all productimg objects of a single product i.e mainproduct
        product=mainproduct
        )
```

shop:view [works]

```
def detail_view(request, slug):
    products = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    productimg = ProductImage.objects.filter(product=products)
```

shop:model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)    

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='somewhere/')
```

home:model

```
class MainProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: `mainproduct` is not a ingle product: it is a `QuerySet` of *all* `MainProduct`s.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsemit contains only one product cuz it has a limit

Comment: @me_zoo: that doesn't matter: it is still a *collection* of objects.

Comment: @me_zee You should fetch one product in that line, first send it in url and if can't pass slug, so send its id or pk, then access in the view and filter something like `ProductImage.objects.filter(product=single_product)`.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsemit if I run mainproduct.get then I would still need to filter out all the rest of the products with something but I don't think I can cuz it's the homepage, so what do I do?

Comment: @me_zee You should learn model relationships as well as field lookups and querysets. See [querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/), [models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/) and [field-lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/lookups/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mainproduct` is not a single product: it is a `QuerySet` of *all* `MainProduct`s, even if there is a single `MainProduct`. If there is exactly one `MainProduct`, you query with [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get):

```py
def home(request):
    mainproduct = MainProduct.objects.get()
    productimg = ProductImage.objects.filter(
       product__mainproduct=mainproduct
    )
```